# Broken Routing/Action in Web API

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have my default route defined in WebApiConfig.cs:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, page = 20, offset = 0 }
        );
```

and in my controller, I have an action:

```
    // GET api/users
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<User> Get(string id, int page, int offset)
    {
        return id != null 
            ? new User[]{Get(id)} 
            : _userService.All().Skip(offset*page).Take(page);
    }
```

I know this was recently working, but now I'm getting the infamous "No action was found on the controller 'Users' that matches the request" error. I can't seem to figure what (if anything) changed. I've undone all my changes since adding the defaults for page/offset and still nothing.

any ideas?

request url: `http://localhost/api/api/Users`

Comment: how your `url` looks like for this action?

Comment: @CuongLe http://localhost/api/api/Users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here parameter 'id' is optional, but the action selector expects to specify a default value for it on the action.

public IEnumerable Get(string id **= null**, int page, int offset)

Also regarding the url, probably a typo, you mean `http://localhost/api/Users` and not `http://localhost/**api/api**/Users`

Comment: updating the route def to `id = ""` instead of `id = RouteParameter.Optional` seems to get it working again. Now I need to see what may have broken as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified an Action in your route. You either need to add an `{action}` piece to your URL, or specify the action in your `default` object.

Comment: Unlikely the case as shown registration is [default](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) one for Web-API (notice `MapHttpRoute` - not the `MapRoute`)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: You still need an action. The default route of the WebAPI also contains one.

Comment: There was never an action in the route. This is the default set up by the mvc 4 web api project.